# Proving a certain differentiable map between smooth manifolds is smooth after altering the differential structure

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ be a $C^1$-differentiable manifold and $\rho : \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ the standard projection map $(x,y) \mapsto x$. As $M$ has a $C^1$ differential structure $\alpha$, there exists a unique smooth differential structure $\beta \subset \alpha$ of $M$ (i.e. every chart in $\beta$ is a chart in $\alpha$); we shall refer to $M^\alpha$ as the set $M$ with differential structure $\alpha$ and $M^\beta$ as the set $M$ with differential structure $\beta$.

What I now wish to show is that $\rho : M^\beta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map. Possibly the answer is obvious but I am unsure as how to approach it, since $M^\beta$ is not obviously a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ any more. The map $\rho :M^\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$-differentiable, hence $\rho : M^\beta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ must also be $C^1$-differentiable at the very least.

Comment: Here is maybe a better formulation of the problem, that avoids $C^1$-atlases all together: Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $h:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is a $C^1$-embedding (i.e. of class $C^1$ and a homeomorphism onto the image), is the pull-back $h^*\rho$ smooth? In order to answer this question, I suggest to consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^1$ (but not $C^2$) and let $h(x)=(f(x),x)$ be the embedding of $M=\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ as graph of $f$. Then $h^*\rho= f$ and ...

Comment: @JanBohr brilliant counter-example, thank you very much!